# String Encoding

Tags: c#, encoding

I am checking for the existence of a file in the XML backup of my iTunes library.

How do I change this string

`E:\Entertainment\Music\Latin\100% Azucar  The Best of Celia Cruz & La Sonora Matancera/08 Mi Soncito.mp3`

to this

`E:/Entertainment/Music/Latin/100%25%20Azucar%20%20The%20Best%20of%20Celia%20Cruz%20&#38;%20La%20Sonora%20Matancera/08%20Mi%20Soncito.mp3`

Changes:

1. Space becomes %20
2. Backslash becomes Forward-slash
3. % (percentage sign) became %25

Comment: You forgot that `&` became `&#38;`. Which is kinda weird - I would expect it to become `%26`.

Comment: @Vilx: It becomes `%26` when you URIEncode it. Perhaps you're thinking of HTMLEncoding.

Comment: @Vilx: On second look, you're right. Perhaps the string needs to be HTMLEncoded, too.

Comment: but is E: a protocol? If it is an URI it should be like file:///E:/Entertainment/Music/Latin/100%25%20Azucar%20%20The%20Best%20of%20Celia%20Cruz%20&#38;%20La%20Sonora%20Matancera/08%20Mi%20Soncito.mp3

Comment: @Caspar: You are correct. In order to load it up into a `Uri`, we may need to prefix with the "file:" protocol. In this case, it looks like we'd want to remove it after we finish our processing, or else we'd load it up and extract the pieces individually. I'm thinking the latter, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple route:

`filepath.Replace("\", "/").Replace("%", "%25").Replace(" ", "%20").Replace("&", "&#38;")`

Comment: This only works for this specific case. When other characters are encoded, this fails.

Comment: I couldn't find an enconding scheme that matched was iTunes was using, so I had to go this route1

Answer (score 7):

Looks like two separate things:

1) Replacing backslash with forward slash.

2) Applying URI-encoding.

The first is obvious. For the second, you have some choices, including `Uri.EscapeDataString`, `Uri.EscapeUriString`, `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode`.

*edit*

3) As Vilx noticed, there seems to be HtmlEncoding of the filename portion.

Maybe the best answer is to use the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri_members.aspx) class to slice and dice the parts, encoding them as needed.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the key part of his problem. It's kinda hidden there, being the first sentence and all, so nobody noticed it much. XD

> I am checking for the existence of a file in the XML backup of my iTunes library.

It seems to me that we are dealing with some rogue iTunes-XML encoding, which has messed up a bit somewhere along the line. My advice would be to go the other way round - decode the iTunes string (first through HtmlDecode, then UrlDecode) and then compare it to the original string you are looking for. This should be able to cope with most mis-encodings of iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

%20 means space character. i see that you want to do something more with this string, so may i ask you what tools you'll prefer to use? regex? string replaces?

Comment: that's kind of what he's asking us ;)

Comment: Tomasz, URI-encoding does replace spaces with `%20`, but it also replaces many other characters. This means `String.Replace` is not a good solution. As for RegExp, that's overkill.

Comment: that's why i asked what tools he'd prefer, so that i can write proper code ;]

Comment: I think the idea here is that he wants it to work, so he's asking you to select the tool.

Answer (score 0):

You do it with `Uri.EscapeDataString()` static method. Super easy.

Comment: No, this will escape the backslashes instead of converting them. In other words, you still need to do a `Replace` first.